# ion-input click into text odd behavior

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I am seeing some very odd behavior of my ion-input field when i click inside of it.  I have pinpointed it (and not sure why) to the padding-top in the parent div.  I also noticed that if I scale back the text to a few words in the p.  Any thoughts as to why this is happening or how i can fix it?

.main

```
.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-top: 100px; // IF I REMOVE THIS, IT IS NORMAL

  &.no-nav {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  &.no-content {
    :before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      height: 1px;
      width: calc(100% - 48px);
      border-bottom: 1px solid $surface-03;
      top: 96px;
      left: 24px;
    }
  }
  &.top-nav {
    padding-top: 24px;
  }
}
```

template code

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="main">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>a bunch of text here that seems to push the input box in click down, if i only put a few words here it doesn't behave  like this which is odd</p>
        <form [formGroup]="" novalidate>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input
              formControlName=""
              required
              inputmode="text"
              placeholder="Click in me"
            ></ion-input>
            <ion-icon class="edit-icon"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        </form>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the behavior

[image]

Comment: it is working fine please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vxsrxs

Comment: odd, thank you for doing that.  I will have to try and find out what other css is causing that behavior on me.

Comment: i noticed when inspecting your code, that random div isn't showing up like it does in my (see gif).  Is that some sort of behavior i have enabled somehow?  It shows up on the click and then immediately disappears

Comment: I was on an ionic 5 beta, i updated to the latest and it seemed to resolve the issue for me.  Thanks for the help